Is the change of trivialisations on a principal $G$-bundle given above each basepoint by a right-multiplication with a group element?
Let $\pi: M \rightarrow B$ be a principal $G$-bundle. Suppose $(U_i, \phi_i)$, $(U_j, \phi_j)$ are two (equivariant) trivialisations $\phi_i: \pi^{-1}(U_i) \rightarrow U_i \times G$ (similarly for $\phi_j$). Suppose $U_i \cap U_j \neq \emptyset$.
We then obtain a map $\phi_{i,j}: U_i \cap U_j \rightarrow Homeom(G)$ given by $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}\rvert_{\pi^{-1}(U_i \cap U_j)}$.
My question is, is it true that for each $b \in U_i \cap U_j$ there exists a $g(b) \in G$ such that $\phi_{i,j}(b)(y) = (b, g(b)y)$?
In other words, are changes of trivialisation given on each fiber by multiplication with an element in the group? I suspect that this is the case, but I can't see how to use the equivariance of $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ to deduce this.

Yes. Over $b$, we have an identification $\psi\colon G\xrightarrow[\cong]{\phi_i|_b^{-1}}\pi^{-1}(b)\xrightarrow[\cong]{\phi_j|_b} G$, which is equivariant under the right multiplication by $G$. Define $g(b):=\psi(e)$, then equivariance tells you $\psi(y)=\psi(e)y=g(b)y$ for all $y\in G$.

What I'm asking is essentially why does equivariance tell me that $\psi(y) = \psi(e)y$? How do I prove this equality?

Equivariance under the right $G$-multiplication means $\psi(xy)=\psi(x)y$ for all $x,y\in G$. Take $x=e$.

Probably I don't understand the question, why the map $y\mapsto g(b)y$ should be a homomorphism of $G$?
The (right) multiplication by a fixed element of a group  is not in general an homomorphism of the group.
